# Bower commands with list and cwd in node

Tags: node.js, bower

I am trying to get the packages installed in a particular folder using nodejs and bower api.

My folder structure is like this

```
  some-folder
     |
     +-- components
             |
             +-- jquery
             |
             +-- polymer
  src
    |
     --js
        |
        +-- tracker.js
        |
        +-- server.js
```

I am using the bower api in `tracker.js` to grab the bower packages installed in the `components` directory.

Here is the code that I am using

```
    bower.commands
    .list()
    .on('end', (results) => {
        console.log(results)
    });
```

Every time, the results obtained is an empty object.

I have also tried the bower api with cwd

```
    bower.commands
    .list(undefined, undefined, {
        cwd: '../../some-folder'
    })
    .on('end', (results) => {
        console.log(results)
    });
```

But still nothing. I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a bower configuration file `.bowercc` at the root and fill it with

```
{
  "directory" : "some-folder/components"
}
```

then run `bower install`

Comment: The solution works, but what if I have multiple component directories.

Comment: Like a separate one for css and js? Or like a copy of the same folder on a different directory?

Comment: More like a component folder in `some-folder` in the root directory and another component folder in `temp/original` directory.

Comment: What is the relation between the 'some folder' in the root directory, and the other 'temp/original' directory. Maybe just use Git for version control?

Or you want the bower_components to be accessed offline?

Comment: its more like user1 has a different set of components installed for one app and user2 has different set of components installed for another app. So I am just trying to grab the components installed by 1st user in folder1 and 2nd user in folder2.

Comment: Regarding your question. There is no relation between root folder and `some-folder` or any other component folder.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand, you want to list all the components that all users are using. I don't think bower supports this (I could be wrong), you could find and read all the bower.json files, throw them in an array and render them in a view?

Comment: Do you need the paths as well? or just the versions?

Comment: I think parsing bower.json file could return the data what I am looking for. But wont let anyone install a new package. Right?

Comment: Well you can add the dependency to the object then overwrite the file. Maybe [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) can help you.